# JSfiddle not evaluating AngularJs $scope variables

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I am trying to make a fiddle to ask for help with a problem which I am having.

I based on an existing [Angular empty fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/ADukg/) and have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mawg/Lqpycjzt/2/)

However, when I try to evaluate `$scope` variables in my HTML, by surrounding them by double braces, the value is not show, the brace-wrapped expression is.

For instance, to evaluate `$scope.myValue`, I have `{{myValue}}` in my HTML, but it actually gets displayed as `{{myValue}}`, not the value of `myValue`.

Please take a look at my fiddle & tell me what I am doing wrongly.

Comment: First as console shows clearly  http source will not work use https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js instead 
second controller declartion should be like my.controller('myCtrl',function(){})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are trying to load angular over HTTP but the fiddle is loaded on HTTPS. So it will block the requests for angular as you can see from the console errors.

Second you have forgotten your braces for function call.

```
<td>{{ShowManagerStuff(managers.details, manager)}}</td>
```

**Working Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lqpycjzt/9/

Answer (score 1):

There are few things with the code, use angular version 1.4 and above and change the controller as,

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
```

Instead of declaring globally. also choose load type as wrap in body,

[image]

**[`WORKING FIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/emmjhhb0/)**

Comment: You should add console error "The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/mawg/Lqpycjzt/2/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." to your explanation